# SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal with ast.parse

Tags: python, parsing, syntax-error, abstract-syntax-tree

The following the valid python code

```
In [49]: print('hello\n')
hello
```

but when I use ast module's parse method it returns, the Syntax error

```
In [47]: code = "print('hello\n')"

In [48]: ast.parse(code)
  File "<unknown>", line 1
    print('hello
           ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal

In [51]: eval(code)
  File "<string>", line 1
    print('hello
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

why is ast module not able to parse the valid python code in this case?

Comment: `code = "print('''hello\n''')"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write:

```
code = "print('hello\\n')"
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to escape the `\` in code

```
code = "print('hello\\n')"
ast.parse(code)
# <_ast.Module object at 0x7fd68cb48cc0>
```

Or you can add `r` prefix to indicate everything in the string needs to be escaped

```
code = r"print('hello\n')"
ast.parse(code)
# <_ast.Module object at 0x7fd68cb48ef0>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use multiline comment `'''YourCode'''` or `"""YourCode"""`

**Ex:**

```
import ast
code = "print('''hello\n''')"
print(ast.parse(code))
```